# Expectation of a random variable that takes points in the natural numbers

Tags: probability

Let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{N} $ be a r.v. Then $$ \mathbb{E} \{ X \} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X > n) $$

#### Attempt:

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ X \} = \sum_j j P(X = j ) = \sum_j j(1 - P(X > j) - P(X<j ) )$$

But here it gets complicated. Am I on the right track?

Comment: [Same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170886/how-to-comprehend-ex-int-0-infty-px-xdx-and-ex-sum-limits) with answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_jjP(X=j)=\sum_jj(P(X>j)-P(X>j-1))$$
and then rearrange that.

Comment: greater than or equal to ??

Answer (score 3):

\begin{equation}
E(X) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}jP(X=j) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}P(X=j) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}P(X=j) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X>k)
\end{equation}
The crucial step is to swap the two sums.

Comment: what are the rules to swap sums like that ? seems like magic to me !

Comment: Hey Marc, could you by any chance explain the steps you undertake? Unfortunately, I don't even understand the first transformation.

Answer (score 0):

In

$$ E(X)=\sum_{j=0}^∞jP(X=j)=\sum_{j=0}^∞j(P(X\ge j)−P(X\ge j+1))$$

$$ \sum_{j=0}^∞j(P(X\ge j)−P(X\ge j+1))=P(X\ge 1) - P(X\ge 2)+2P(X\ge 2)-2P(X\ge 3)+3P(X\ge 3)-3P(X\ge 4)+... $$

$$ \sum_{j=0}^∞j(P(X\ge j)−P(X\ge j+1))=\sum_{j=1}^∞P(X\ge j)$$

which is

$$ \sum_{j=0}^∞P(X\gt j)$$